# Is it possible to delete a foreign key using @DeleteMapping in java spring hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

In other words change it to null on click. My reason for this is I have a main employees list and employees assigned to a project. I want to figure out a way to remove employees from the projects list without deleting them from the main total employees list as well.

For example this deletes an employee from the main list.

```
    @DeleteMapping("/jpa/users/{username}/employees/{employeeId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteEmployee(
            @PathVariable String username, @PathVariable Long employeeId) {

        employeeJpaRepository.deleteById(employeeId);

        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
```

But how do I delete the foreign key (projectId) of @DeleteMapping("/jpa/users/{username}/projects/{projectId}/employees/{employeeId}")?

Comment: If ur mappings are correct u should be able to just remove the project from the Java objects attribute of projects (I assume a collection) and then update the entity to persist the change

Answer (score 1):

You can have a single query in EmployeeRepository sth like below to delete the records efficiently. if the request contains a invalid combination of username and employeeId, it will not do anything which is what we usually want.

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "delete from Employee e where e.id = :empId and e.user_id= (select id from User u where u.username = :username) ")
void deleteEmployee(Long empId, String username);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the employee from the collection, something like this:

```
@DeleteMapping("/jpa/users/{username}/employees/{employeeId}")
public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteEmployee(
        @PathVariable String username, @PathVariable Long employeeId) {
    User u = userJpaRepository.findByUsername(username);
    u.getEmployees().removeIf(e -> e.getId().equals(employeeId));
    userJpaRepository.save(u);

    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
}
```

Comment: `u.getEmployees()` would fetch all employees from DB. We should avoid that

Comment: In that case you should probably consider mapping the join table as entity